# How do I properly implement a display function of a class?

Tags: c++, function

I have a class called magicSquare with a constructor and a display function called display. The constructor creates the magic square, and the display function displays the results. In my main function, I created an instance of magicSquare called ms and gave it a value 7. To display it, shouldn't it work if I just did ms.display()?

```
class magicSquare
{
private:

int size, square;
vector<vector <int> > finalvec;

public:

magicSquare(int a):finalvec(a, std::vector<int>(a))
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = a/2;

    size = a;
    square = a * a;

    vector<int>vec(a);
    vector<vector<int> >   finalvec(a,vec);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< size; j++)
          cout << finalvec[i][j];
          cout << endl;
    }

    for (int k=0; k < square; ++k)
    {
        finalvec[i][j] = k;
        i--;
        j++;

        if (k%a == 0)
        {
            i = i+ 2;
            --j;
        }
        else
        {
            if (j==a)
              j = j- a;
            else if (i<0)
              i = i+ a;
        }
    }

}

void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j< size; j++)
                cout << finalvec[i][j];
                cout << endl;

    }
}
};


int main()
{
    magicSquare ms(3);
    ms.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Properly indenting your code will help you find at least one error. After that please post the full, compilable code.

Comment: `finalvec` in the magicSquare function hides the `finalvec` member variable.

Answer (score -1):

## Your Error

As pointed by @Retired Ninja, the vector >   finalvec(a,vec); hide your member variable finalvec, as you redefine it as a new vector...

## What can correct it

You could construct your vector inside a [Member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) like this

```
magicSquare(int a) : finalvec(a, std::vector<int>(a, 0)) {
 /* your constructor */
}
```

And delete the two line:

```
vector<int>vec(a);
vector<vector<int> >   finalvec(a,vec);
```

In your code

## How to not make this error

Seeing which value are a class member, method parameter or even context variable can be sometime difficult:

What i can recommend you is to do the following:

```
 class member      -> m_NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS_MEMBER
 method parameter  -> t_NAME_OF_YOUR_METHODE_PARAMETER
 context variable  -> c_NAME_OF_YOUR_CONTEXT_VARIABLE
```

by doing this error like you've done is a bit harder to do!

## EDIT: After testing your code

I see there's error in it, effectively, the first time you go in that line:

```
finalvec[i][j] = k;
```

i > size, so you access further that your vector allow it, which result in a segfault! please repair your code!

*hope that can help*

Comment: That only initializes the outer vector to a size, not the vectors inside it.  You would need `finalvec(a, std::vector<int>(a))` to make both the outer and inner vectors the same size.

Comment: I added magicSquare(int a): finalvec(a, std::vector<int>(a)) and my program outputs numbers but the incorrect ones.

Comment: @user3598181 because you still have the two lines said in you code, look better at my answer..., furthermore, when i test your code there is still error in it (i segfault at line `finalvec[i][j] = k;` )